# Multipling Elements across three ArrayLists in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

1. I'm creating two `ArrayLists` from pre-defined arrays.
2. I need to take each element of the two `ArrayLists` and multiple the values, with the answers being stored in a third `ArrayList`. For example: `ListA[0] * ListB[0] = ListC[0]`
3. I need to output all three lists to the console.

I have the first lists created and populated, but it is the calculation method `extend` that is throwing me off. Code of what I have is listed below. Can anyone offer any insight as to what I am missing here?

```
package threeArrayLists;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ThreeArrayLists {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    double [] price_Array = {10.62, 14.89, 13.21, 16.55, 18.62, 9.47, 6.58, 18.32, 12.15, 3.98};
    double [] quantity_Array = {4.0, 8.5, 6.0, 7.35, 9.0, 15.3, 3.0, 5.4, 2.9, 4.8};

    ArrayList<Double> priceList = new ArrayList<Double>();
    ArrayList<Double> quantityList = new ArrayList<Double>();
    ArrayList<Double> amountList = new ArrayList<Double>();

    for (int i = 0; i < price_Array.length; i++) {
      priceList.add(price_Array[i]);
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < quantity_Array.length; j++) {
      quantityList.add(quantity_Array[j]);
    }

    extend(priceList, quantityList, amountList);
  }

  private static void extend(ArrayList<Double> prices,
                             ArrayList<Double> quantity,
                             ArrayList<Double> amount) {
    for (int k = 0; k < prices.size() && k < quantity.size(); k++) {
      amount.add(prices[k] * quantity[k]);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need lists at all? From the code in your post this is not clear,
and there is no visible reason for using a list.
The implementation can be more shorter and simpler by using only arrays:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] priceArray = {10.62, 14.89, 13.21, 16.55, 18.62, 9.47, 6.58, 18.32, 12.15, 3.98};
    double[] quantityArray = {4.0, 8.5, 6.0, 7.35, 9.0, 15.3, 3.0, 5.4, 2.9, 4.8};

    double[] amountArray = multiply(priceArray, quantityArray);
}

private static double[] multiply(double[] prices, double[] quantity) {
    double[] result = new double[prices.length + quantity.length];
    for (int k = 0; k < prices.length && k < quantity.length; k++) {
        result[k] = prices[k] * quantity[k];
    }
    return result;
}
```

If you really want to use Lists:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Double[] priceArray = {10.62, 14.89, 13.21, 16.55, 18.62, 9.47, 6.58, 18.32, 12.15, 3.98};
    Double[] quantityArray = {4.0, 8.5, 6.0, 7.35, 9.0, 15.3, 3.0, 5.4, 2.9, 4.8};

    List<Double> priceList = Arrays.asList(priceArray);
    List<Double> quantityList = Arrays.asList(quantityArray);
    List<Double> amountList = multiply(priceList, quantityList);
}

private static List<Double> multiply(List<Double> prices, List<Double> quantity) {
    List<Double> result = new ArrayList<Double>();
    for (int k = 0; k < prices.size() && k < quantity.size(); k++) {
        result.add(prices.get(k) * quantity.get(k));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Notes:

- Whenever possible, prefer to declare variables by interface type instead of implementation type, for example `List<Double>` instead of `ArrayList<Double>`
- It's not a good idea to pass a list to a void method for modifications. It's better to make that method create the list and return it
- Variable names in Java should be `camelCase`, no underscores (no `_` characters)
- A neat trick: if you change the type of an array from `double[]` to `Double[]`, you can easily convert it to a list using `Arrays.asList`, like I did in the above example

Comment: Although this is certainly an improvement, the problem really doesn't need `List`s at all. Arrays alone would accomplish his goal more succinctly.

Comment: @janos...thanks for the reply. This is part of a school assignment, so the ArrayLists are required. After reading over the rest of your reply, I can see how arrays would work as well. I have everything up and running now.

Answer (score 0):

`prices` and `quantity` aren't arrays, they are [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)s. They don't support the `[]` operator, but you can use the `get(int)` method to access their elements:

```
for(int k = 0; k < prices.size() && k < quantity.size(); k++)
{
    amount.add(prices.get(k) * quantity.get(k));
}
```